# List all real users on Linux/*nix and data associated with them

Tags: c, linux, list, haskell

Hello I'd like to list all real users on Linux/*nix and it's data. I probably need to parse `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` and check if user have password.

The problem is that is not cross-platform (on *BSD there is no `/etc/shadow`). Is there any cross-platform library/command I can use?

Comment: What is a 'real user' as opposed to a 'fake user', or is it a 'complex user'?  Does 'root' count?  What about 'bin' and 'sys' and the various daemons?  How do you plan to distinguish between them and the real users?  Are you going to deal with network-based password databases?

Comment: root may or may not count. By real users I mean users which accounts are not only for running daemons.

Comment: I'd prefer Haskell but Haskell has FFI and I do know C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See man pages for getpwent.

```
   The getpwent() function returns a pointer to a structure containing the
   broken-out  fields  of  a  record from the password database (e.g., the
   local password file /etc/passwd, NIS, and LDAP).
```

I will add that if you want to check the passwords, look at getspent, getspnam for listing the shadow password file. The man page says that the getspent etc. functions might not be cross-platform though.

Comment: You could call `getpwent()` and check if the shell ends in `sh` - system users often have something like `/bin/false` as their "shell".

Comment: Unless someone have chosen `tmux` or `screen` as logging shell ;) However there is `/etc/shells` file.